# Calculate running pace from distance and time in PHP

Tags: php, pace

I'm not a programator, I'm not a student. I just play with HTML, CSS and PHP for my own pleasure. For now, I try to make a webpage for my running.
I would like to calculate my PACE (mm:ss/KM) from my DISTANCE (KM) and running time (mm:ss) or better (hh:mm:ss).

Can anyone help to PHP begginer? I have no idea how to code it.

```
<?php
$distance="6.03";
$hours="00";
$minutes="34";
$seconds="13";

$time=($hours*3600)+($minutes*60)+$seconds;
$speed=($time/$distance)/60;
$speed1=date('i:s', $speed);
?>
```

$distance is 6.03 km
$time gives me rum time in seconds (2053 seconds)
$speed gives mi number 5.67440574903 
$speed1 gives me 00:05

Comment: it's just basic maths, think about it logically.. `$speed = $km / $time`

Comment: Basic maths ... so I do it somewhere wrong ...

Comment: I have no idea if you did it somewhere wrong you've posted no code friend :)

Comment: Basic maths ... so I do it somewhere wrong ... $distance="6.03"; $hours="00"; $minutes="34"; $seconds="13"; $time=($hours*3600)+($minutes*60)+$seconds; $speed=($time/$distance)/60; I have distance in KM, time in SECONDS and speed gives me 5.67440574903 minutes if am I right. Can somebody help me convert that number to mm:ss? I try date('i:s', $speed); but it gives to me 00:05

Comment: update your question with the code - that's unreadable haha

Comment: First time here, can you help me, le me know how to write a code to this comment please?

Comment: use backticks to format - but I'd still recommend putting it in the post rather than the comment

Comment: What is `time1` if you don't divide by 60..?

Comment: Speed (time1 not divide by 60) is 340,464344

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! Many thanks to BizziBob

This is correct working code:

```
<?php 
$distance="6.03";
$hours="00";
$minutes="34";
$seconds="13";

$time=($hours*3600)+($minutes*60)+$seconds;
$speed=$time/$distance;
$formated=date('i:s', $speed);

echo $formated;
?>
```